# Best layout for graph with long node labels

Tags: layout, visualization, graphviz

My graph has long node labels. Neato makes things overlap; Circo does what I want, it just creates too much space between nodes. I would like to use the Circo result and bring the nodes closer together.

Graph code: https://clbin.com/BbsNP

```
digraph {
graph [overlap=scale];
graph [bgcolor=white];
node [shape=box];
0 [label="long node label"
  ,shape=box];
1 [label="long node label"
  ,shape=box];
2 [label="aoeu aoe uaoeu oae ueaoo"
  ,shape=box];
3 [label="long node labelau"
  ,shape=box];
4 [label="aoeu aoe uaoeu oae ueaooeu"
  ,shape=box];
5 [label="long node labelaoeu"
  ,shape=box];
6 [label="aoeu aoe uaoeu oae ueaoe"
  ,shape=box];
7 [label="long node labelaoeuo"
  ,shape=box];
8 [label="aoeu aoe uaoeu oae ueao"
  ,shape=box];
9 [label="234 aoeua",shape=box];
10 [label="long node labeluu"
   ,shape=box];
11 [label="aoeu aoe uaoeu oae ueao"
   ,shape=box];
12 [label=oeuaoeu,shape=box];
13 [label="long node labelaa"
   ,shape=box];
14 [label="aoeu aoe uaoeu oae ueao"
   ,shape=box];
15 [label=aoeu,shape=box];
16 [label=aoeu,shape=box];
0 -> 1 [color=blue];
1 -> 0 [color=blue];
2 -> 1 [color=blue];
3 -> 0 [color=blue];
4 -> 3 [color=blue];
5 -> 0 [color=blue];
6 -> 5 [color=blue];
7 -> 0 [color=blue];
8 -> 7 [color=blue];
9 -> 7 [color=blue];
10 -> 0 [color=blue];
11 -> 10 [color=blue];
12 -> 10 [color=blue];
13 -> 0 [color=blue];
14 -> 13 [color=blue];
15 -> 13 [color=blue];
16 -> 13 [color=blue];
}
```

Image: http://postimage.org/image/mrcak2021/

```
circo -T jpg Test.Layout.LongNodeLabel.dot > Test.Layou.LongNodeLabel.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is similar to the one in [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749885/control-spacing-in-twopi-graphviz). If you're willing to use `twopi` rather than `circo`, you can set [`ranksep`](https://web.archive.org/web/20171107200610/http://www.graphviz.org:80/content/attrs#dranksep) to pull in or push out the nodes -- to change "the radial separation of concentric circles," as the documentation describes it.

I changed your graph code to begin like so:

```
digraph {
    graph [bgcolor=white, overlap=true, ranksep=2.75];
```

Then graphed it using `twopi`: `twopi test_graph.txt -Tpng -otest_graph.png`. This produces the following graph:

[image: graph using twopi]

Here is the original for comparison:

[image: graph using circo]

Comment: btw: you can continue using dot, and specify twopi in the .dot file like so: `graph [bgcolor=white, overlap=true, ranksep=2.75 layout=twopi]`